# 'StaticDedupe' object has no attribute 'match' error in my Python script

Tags: python

```
logger.info('Clustering.....')
clustered_dupes = deduper.match(data_d, threshold=0.5)
logger.info('Clustering completed')

logger.info(str(len(clustered_dupes)) +' duplicate sets')
clustered_dupes_list=list(clustered_dupes)
```

When running my Python script above I encounter the following errors:

```
File "<ipython-input-2-338d12285e67>", line 307, in <module>
   clustered_dupes = deduper.match(data_d, threshold=0.5)

AttributeError: 'StaticDedupe' object has no attribute 'match'
```

I am not sure what the error is, is there a problem with the dedupe library?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, your code does not allow for reproduction of the problem. Please make sure to provive an [mre] when submitting a question.

Comment: Found any work around to this problem?

Comment: Not sure what's not clear from the error... The class `StaticDupe` doesn't have any `match` attribute/method that I could find in the [docs](https://docs.dedupe.io/en/latest/API-documentation.html#dedupe.StaticDedupe)